# Enzyme wont 'render, mount, or shallow' a component because a dependency is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon, enzyme, styled-components

I am trying to figure out why my test wont run. I have a React functional component that contains a styled-component which uses a custom method to generate a media query which gets imported for a css helper file. I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'medium' of undefined`. Here is my code.

## css/index.js

```
export const media = (function(){

  const sizes = {
    large: 996,
    medium: 767,
    small: 656,
  };

  return Object.keys(sizes).reduce((acc, label) => {
    acc[label] = (...args) => css`
      @media (min-width: ${sizes[label] / 16}em) {
        ${css(...args)}
      }
    `;
    return acc;
  }, {});

})();
```

## mycomponent

```
import { media } from 'css';

const MyComponent = ({ icon, title, description }) => (
  <MyComponentContainer>
    ...
  </MyComponentContainer>
);

export default MyComponent;

const MyComponentContainer = styled.article`
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  ${media.medium`
    padding: 0 25px;
  `}
  ${media.large`
    max-width: 350px;
  `}
`;
```

## My Test File

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent';

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {

  it('should match the snapshot', () => {

    const snap = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(snap).toMatchSnapshot();

  });

});
```

I am new to react testing and don't really understand how to mock that functionality or tell jest to ignore it.

### I am using react 16+ with the required enzyme adapter and the `jest-styled-components` test plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs across this, I found the answer, and it explains a lot about the nature of testing.

When you are testing, you only want to the test the functionality of one component or action at a time (UNIT TESTING). By trying to test a component that was pulling in another dependency, I was actually trying to test two things at once without realizing it.

The `MyComponent` component needs to be tested separate from the `media` tagged template methods.

In `MyComponent`, I don't care what was returned from the `media` tagged template method. I only care what method was called and the parameters of the invocation.

I can setup another separate test for the `media` methods to make sure those methods behave as expected and test those individually.

So in `jest` you can mock the module import.

## inside My Test File

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import MyComponent from 'components';

jest.mock('css', () => ({
   media: {
      small: jest.fn(),
      medium: jest.fn(),
      large: jest.fn(),
   },
})

describe('<MyComponent />, () => {
    it('should match snapshot', () => {
        const snap = shallow(<MyComponent />);
        expect(snap).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```